# I Want Access To a Public Static Const in my Actionscript Without Instantiating an Object... Is That Possible?

Tags: actionscript-3, class, constants

I've got a static property I would like to access by importing it's class without instantiating an object of that class.  Is this possible?

Essentially I'm writing a bunch of styleSheet Objects over and over.  I figure If I have a class called CSS and like this:

```
package com
{
    import flash.text.*;

   public class CSS
   {  

    public static var STYLE_SHEET:StyleSheet = new StyleSheet();
```

and assign all of it's properties in the constructor like:

```
public function CSS
   {
          //NAV BUTTON
        var navButtonBlock:Object = new Object();
        navButtonBlock.color = "#000000";
        navButtonBlock.fontSize = "25";
        navButtonBlock.fontFamily = "Arial";
        navButtonBlock.marginLeft = "5";
        navButtonBlock.kerning = "true";
        navButtonBlock.fontWeight = "bold";

        //TITLE
        var titleBlock:Object = new Object();
        titleBlock.color = "#CCCCCC";
        titleBlock.fontSize = "25";
        titleBlock.fontFamily = "Arial";
        titleBlock.marginLeft = "5";
        titleBlock.kerning = "true";
        titleBlock.fontWeight = "bold";

        STYLE_SHEET.setStyle("code", titleBlock);
        STYLE_SHEET.setStyle("navButton", navButtonBlock);
}
```

If I import the class into the class I wish to make use of it like:

```
package{
 import com.CSS;
```

and inside my class use the variable like:

```
textField.styleSheet = CSS.STYLE_SHEET;
```

I can save some headaches.
The thing I find weird is that I have create an instance of that class to access it's const. So in the class header I have to write:

```
private var css:CSS = new CSS();
```

even though I never end up making use of this object...
Does this make sense?  Am I going about this the wrong way?

-J
p.s. Who wishes the tab key worked in this question editor window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write static init() function, which you will have call only once or you can use "static initializers":

```
package com
{
   import flash.text.*;

   public class CSS
   {  
       public static var STYLE_SHEET:StyleSheet = new StyleSheet();

       // Static init block
       // This block is run once when the class is first accessed
       {
           var navButtonBlock:Object = new Object();
           /*...*/
           var titleBlock:Object = new Object();
           /*...*/
           STYLE_SHEET.setStyle("code", titleBlock);
           STYLE_SHEET.setStyle("navButton", navButtonBlock);
        }
    }
}
```

Now import class and just use static var STYLE_SHEET

```
import com.CSS;
...
textField.styleSheet = CSS.STYLE_SHEET;
```

Comment: That is wicked! I did not know about this! Very nice! +1

Comment: @ivann, I just found out you can't declare variables in a static function... but you CAN call a function... I'll post the final solution.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to make an instance of the class to **ACCESS** its static members, but you are initiating your static variable inside the classes constructor.

This mean that at the time you access the static variable like this:

```
textField.styleSheet = CSS.STYLE_SHEET;
```

The STYLE_SHEET property is not set yet!

Usually the way to get around this kind of thing is to have an "init" static method.

```
CSS.init();
```

The init method would set STYLE_SHEET, like you have done in your constructor.

This does mean that in you application you will have to call CSS.init() once before you use STYLE_SHEET anywhere else.

ALSO:
What you refer to as a "const", is not a const at all. It is just a static. Const means the value is constant (never changes).

Comment: Makes total sense.  Thank you.   -J

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to both ivann and TandemAdam for leading me down the right path.  Ultimately I figured out that first, the reason I had to instantiate an instance of my class is because I was defining my variables properties in the constructor function.  So I built a static constructor function which eliminated the need to instantiate, but I still had to call the function (rather than just import).

Then, ivann pointed out, I don't need to call the function at all If I just build a static init() function.  Awesome idea except missing one bit of information.  You cannot declare variables in a static initializer.  So, the ultimate solution was to call my private static function that CAN declare variables from my static initilaizer function.

example:

```
package com.atJascha
{
    import flash.text.*;

   public class CSS
   {  

    public static var STYLE_SHEET:StyleSheet = new StyleSheet();

        {
            init();
        }
        private static function init()
        {
            //NAV BUTTON
            var navButtonBlock:Object = new Object();
            navButtonBlock.color = "#FFFFFF";


            //TITLE
            var titleBlock:Object = new Object();
            titleBlock.color = "#00FFFF";

            STYLE_SHEET.setStyle("navButton", navButtonBlock);
            STYLE_SHEET.setStyle("title", titleBlock);

        }

   }

}
```